# Making new layer from script derived from ModelBuilder

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

I am new to Python and using ModelBuilder as a starting point for my script.
My objective is to add a new field, called LTS, and populate it with a number of 1-4 given a set of conditions based on other attributes.

SaveToLayerFile is not producing an output. Why doesn't SaveToLayerFile produce an output based on my code?

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# LTS_11_9.py
# Created on: 2021-11-09 11:55:41.00000
#   (generated by ArcGIS/ModelBuilder)
# Description: 
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

#import other modules you may want to use
import os, sys, pprint as pp

arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:\Users\kahcp\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\ChattanoogaLTS'

#reads shapefile into arcpy layer object
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management ('LTS4_11_8.shp', 'LTS4_11_8_RD')

# Local variables:
Streets_layer = "LTS4_11_8_RD"
Streets_layer__2_ = Streets_layer
Streets_layer__3_ = Streets_layer__2_
Streets_layer__4_ = Streets_layer__3_
Streets_layer__5_ = Streets_layer__4_
Streets_layer__6_ = Streets_layer__5_
Streets_layer__7_ = Streets_layer__6_
Streets_layer__8_ = Streets_layer__7_
Streets_layer__9_ = Streets_layer__8_
Streets_layer__10_ = Streets_layer__9_

# Process: Add Field
arcpy.AddField_management(Streets_layer, "LTS", "SHORT", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Select LTS 1 conditions
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Streets_layer__2_, "NEW_SELECTION", "(LanesPerDi = 1 AND sidepath =1 AND speed <= 20) OR (LanesPerDi = 1 AND sidepath =1 AND speed = 25) OR (LanesPerDi = 1 AND sidepath =1 AND speed = 30) OR (LanesPerDi = 1 AND sidepath =0 AND BL_Width >= 6 AND speed <= 20) OR (LanesPerDi = 1 AND sidepath =0 AND BL_Width >= 6 AND speed = 25) OR (LanesPerDi = 1 AND sidepath =0 AND BL_Width >= 6 AND speed = 30) OR (LanesPerDi = 1 AND sidepath =0 AND (BL_Width > 0 AND BL_Width <6) AND speed <= 20) OR (LanesPerDi = 1 AND sidepath =0 AND (BL_Width > 0 AND BL_Width <6) AND speed = 25) OR (LanesPerDi = 1 And sidepath = 0 And (FC_2 = 'Local_Private' Or FC_2 = 'Local') And BL_Width = 0 And speed <= 20) OR (LanesPerDi = 1 And sidepath = 0 And (FC_2 = 'Local_Private' Or FC_2 = 'Local') And BL_Width = 0 And speed = 25) OR (LanesPerDi = 2 AND sidepath =1 AND speed <= 20) OR (LanesPerDi = 2 AND sidepath =1 AND speed = 25) OR (LanesPerDi = 2 AND sidepath =0 AND BL_Width >= 6 AND speed <= 20) OR (LanesPerDi = 2 AND (FC_2 = 'Local_Private' Or FC_2 = 'Local') AND sidepath =0 AND BL_Width >= 6 AND speed = 25) OR (LanesPerDi = 2 AND sidepath =0 AND (BL_Width > 0 AND BL_Width <6) AND speed <= 20) OR (LanesPerDi = 2 AND  (FC_2 = 'Local_Private' Or FC_2 = 'Local') AND sidepath =0 AND (BL_Width > 0 AND BL_Width <6) AND speed = 25) OR (LanesPerDi = 3 AND sidepath =1 AND speed <= 20)")

# Process: Calculate LTS 1
arcpy.CalculateField_management(Streets_layer__3_, "LTS", "1", "VB", "")

# Process: Select LTS 2 conditions
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Streets_layer__4_, "NEW_SELECTION", "(LanesPerDi = 1 AND sidepath =1 AND speed = 35) OR (LanesPerDi = 1 AND sidepath =1 AND speed >= 40) OR (LanesPerDi = 1 AND sidepath =0 AND (BL_Width > 0 AND BL_Width <6) AND speed = 30) OR (LanesPerDi = 1 And sidepath = 0 And (FC_2 = 'Collector' Or FC_2 = 'Arterial') And BL_Width = 0 And speed <= 20) OR (LanesPerDi = 1 And sidepath = 0 And (FC_2 = 'Collector' Or FC_2 = 'Arterial') And BL_Width = 0 And speed = 25) OR (LanesPerDi = 2 AND sidepath =1 AND speed = 30) OR (LanesPerDi = 2 AND sidepath =1 AND speed = 35) OR (LanesPerDi = 2 AND sidepath =1 AND speed >= 40) OR (LanesPerDi = 2 AND (FC_2 = 'Collector' Or FC_2 = 'Arterial') AND sidepath =0 AND BL_Width >= 6 AND speed = 25) OR (LanesPerDi = 2 AND sidepath =0 AND BL_Width >= 6 AND speed = 30) OR (LanesPerDi = 2 AND  (FC_2 = 'Collector' Or FC_2 = 'Arterial') AND sidepath =0 AND (BL_Width > 0 AND BL_Width <6) AND speed = 25) OR (LanesPerDi = 2 AND sidepath =0 AND (BL_Width > 0 AND BL_Width <6) AND speed = 30) OR (LanesPerDi = 2 And sidepath = 0 And BL_Width = 0 And speed <= 20) OR (LanesPerDi = 2 And sidepath = 0 And (FC_2 = 'Local_Private' Or FC_2 = 'Local') And BL_Width = 0 And speed = 25) OR (LanesPerDi = 3 AND sidepath =1 AND speed = 25) OR (LanesPerDi = 3 AND sidepath =1 AND speed = 30) OR (LanesPerDi = 3 AND sidepath =1 AND speed = 35) OR (LanesPerDi = 3 AND sidepath =1 AND speed >= 40) OR (LanesPerDi = 3 AND sidepath =0 AND BL_Width >= 6 AND speed <= 20) OR (LanesPerDi = 3 AND sidepath =0 AND BL_Width >= 6 AND speed = 25)")

# Process: Calculate LTS 2
arcpy.CalculateField_management(Streets_layer__5_, "LTS", "2", "VB", "")

# Process: Select LTS 3 conditions
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Streets_layer__6_, "NEW_SELECTION", "(LanesPerDi = 1 AND sidepath =0 AND BL_Width >= 6 AND speed = 35) OR (LanesPerDi = 1 AND sidepath =0 AND (BL_Width > 0 AND BL_Width <6) AND speed = 35) OR (LanesPerDi = 1 And sidepath = 0 And BL_Width = 0 And speed = 30) OR (LanesPerDi = 1 And sidepath = 0 And BL_Width = 0 And speed = 35) OR (LanesPerDi = 2 AND sidepath =0 AND BL_Width >= 6 AND speed = 35) OR (LanesPerDi = 2 And sidepath = 0 And (FC_2 = 'Collector' Or FC_2 = 'Arterial') And BL_Width = 0 And speed = 25) OR (LanesPerDi = 3 AND sidepath =0 AND BL_Width >= 6 AND speed = 30) OR (LanesPerDi = 3 AND sidepath =0 AND BL_Width >= 6 AND speed = 35) OR (LanesPerDi = 3 AND sidepath =0 AND (BL_Width > 0 AND BL_Width <6) AND speed <= 20) OR (LanesPerDi = 3 AND sidepath =0 AND (BL_Width > 0 AND BL_Width <6) AND speed = 25) OR (LanesPerDi = 3 AND sidepath =0 AND (BL_Width > 0 AND BL_Width <6) AND speed = 30) OR (LanesPerDi = 3 And sidepath = 0 And BL_Width = 0 And speed <= 20)")

# Process: Calculate LTS 3
arcpy.CalculateField_management(Streets_layer__7_, "LTS", "3", "VB", "")

# Process: Select LTS 4 conditions
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Streets_layer__8_, "NEW_SELECTION", "(LanesPerDi = 1 AND sidepath =0 AND BL_Width >= 6 AND speed >= 40) OR (LanesPerDi = 1 AND sidepath =0 AND (BL_Width > 0 AND BL_Width <6) AND speed = 40) OR (LanesPerDi = 1 And sidepath = 0 And BL_Width = 0 And speed >= 40) OR (LanesPerDi = 2 AND sidepath =0 AND BL_Width >= 6 AND speed >= 40) OR (LanesPerDi = 2 AND sidepath =0 AND (BL_Width > 0 AND BL_Width <6) AND speed = 35) OR (LanesPerDi = 2 AND sidepath =0 AND (BL_Width > 0 AND BL_Width <6) AND speed >= 40) OR (LanesPerDi = 2 And sidepath = 0 And BL_Width = 0 And speed = 30) OR (LanesPerDi = 2 And sidepath = 0 And BL_Width = 0 And speed = 35) OR (LanesPerDi = 2 And sidepath = 0 And BL_Width = 0 And speed >= 40) OR (LanesPerDi = 3 AND sidepath =0 AND BL_Width >= 6 AND speed >= 40) OR (LanesPerDi = 3 AND sidepath =0 AND (BL_Width > 0 AND BL_Width <6) AND speed = 35) OR (LanesPerDi = 3 AND sidepath =0 AND (BL_Width > 0 AND BL_Width <6) AND speed >= 40) OR (LanesPerDi = 3 And sidepath = 0 And BL_Width = 0 And speed = 25) OR (LanesPerDi = 3 And sidepath = 0 And BL_Width = 0 And speed = 30) OR (LanesPerDi = 3 And sidepath = 0 And BL_Width = 0 And speed = 35) OR (LanesPerDi = 3 And sidepath = 0 And BL_Width = 0 And speed >= 40)")

# Process: Calculate LTS 4
arcpy.CalculateField_management(Streets_layer__9_, "LTS", "4", "VB", "")

#Copy Features to new Feature Class
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("LTS4_11_8_RD", "LTS4_11_8_updated")

#saves layer to new layer file
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management ("LTS4_11_8_RD", "LTS4_11_8_updated")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "CopyFeatures and SaveToLayerFile are not doing the trick"? What error messages are you getting? Edit your question and explain.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Questions here should describe the actual error encountered, vice a generic indication of failure. Please [Edit] the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [Save To Layer File](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/save-to-layer-file.htm) documentation example, I believe you need to save the new layer as a '.lyr' as follows:

```
#saves layer to new layer file
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management ("LTS4_11_8_RD", "LTS4_11_8_updated.lyr")
```

That should save a layer file to your current workspace.